# не работает belongsTo laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel5

Есть две модели

```
class game_box extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'data_at_game_boxes';

    /**
    * Получить левелы данного бокса.
    */
   public function levels()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\game_level', 'box_id');
   }
}
```

И

```
class game_level extends Model {
    protected $table = 'data_at_game_levels';

   /**
    * Получить бокс данного левела.
    */
   public function box()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\game_box', 'id');
   }

    /**
    * Получить левелы данного бокса.
    */
   public function questions()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\game_question', 'level_id');
   }

    public function getQuestions ($levelId){
         $level = self::find(1);
         return $level->box;
    }  
}
```

hasMany relation работает нормально и при обращениие отдает данные из модели game_level , при обращении из game_level через belongsTo к родительской модели метод getQuestions ,выдает ошибку:

> Trait   'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Concerns\SupportsDefaultModels' not found

в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем что обновил компосер. Видимо не находило этого файла , после обновления компосер вероятно подтянул все файлы которых не хватало.